# Replace a random subset of regex matches

Tags: python, regex

```py
re.sub(pattern, replacement, text)
```

`re.sub` replaces **every match** in a given string `text`, except if you pass a `count` parameter, then it replaces the **first `count` matches**. Neither is the behaviour I'm aiming for. Instead of replacing the first `count` matches, I want to replace a **random subset of matches (`count` is then the subset size)**.

Is there a straight-forward way to realize this? The only solution I thought of is making use of `re.finditer`, getting all match objects… randomly subsetting them, and then replacing manually with help of the match objects (although I'm not quite aware of good way to implement the last step), like...

```
pattern = "ab"
text = "ab ab ab"
replacement = "ba"
count = 2
match_objects = random.sample(list(re.finditer(pattern, text)), count)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
import re, random

def randsub(pat, repl, text, n):
    matches = random.sample(list(re.finditer(pat, text)), n)

    for i in sorted(matches, key=lambda i: -i.start()):
        text = text[:i.start()] + repl + text[i.end():]

    return text

for i in range(10):
    print(randsub("a{2,3}", "b", "aa|aaa|aa", 2))

b|b|aa
aa|b|b
b|b|aa
b|aaa|b
aa|b|b
b|aaa|b
b|b|aa
b|b|aa
aa|b|b
b|b|aa
```

So, you first get the list of matches (as you do in your question). However, you can't just substitute all of these sequentially, as once you substitute one the others' indexes will be off. So, we sort them from last to first in the string.

Comment: If you sorted them backwards, I guess you wouldn't need the offset?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe count the matches, then pick which ones to replace, then use `re.sub`?

```
matches = len(re.findall(pattern, text))
pick = [1] * count + [0] * (matches - count)
random.shuffle(pick)
text = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: replacement if pick.pop() else m.group(0), text)
```